# Passing data to UITextField for next viewController when didSelectAtRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, didselectrowatindexpath

When I'm trying to pass data from one view controller to another thorough `didSelectRowAt`, the app is crashing.

How to pass the data to textfield of another view controller by using `didSelectAtRow`?

Here is my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let  vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscountDetailsController") as! DiscountDetailsController

     // MARK: This one is not setting data to textField in next view controller
     vc.offerName.text = discountArray?[indexPath.row].offerName

     // vc.offerValue.text = String((discountArray?[indexPath.row].percentage)! )
     // vc.delete.isHidden = false

     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't try to manipulate another view controller's views directly. That violates the principle of encapsulation. (It's bad design, and can cause bugs like the one you are describing.)

Instead, give your `DiscountDetailsController` a String property `offerNameString`. Set that property in your didSelect method above, and then in your `DiscountDetailsController`'s viewWillAppear, install the `offerNameString` into your view as desired.

I don't understand your "...not when passing data it is crashing." statement. Is your code crashing? If so, it might be because your `DiscountDetailsController`'s `offerName` property is an implicitly unwrapped optional which is nil. That would cause a crash.

Comment: In ViewWillAppear how can we add didSelectAtRow method.

Comment: Can you give a referal program, When we select it should display the data in next view controller in text field.

Comment: Refactor the DiscountDetailsController to have a offerNameString property. In your first view controller's didSelectAtRow method (that you posted above) instantiate a DiscountDetailsController, and set the DiscountDetailsController's offerNameString property. Then in the DiscountDetailsController's viewWillAppear, take the value of the offerNameString property and install it in the the desired view.

Comment: Here i'm having three properties know, Then i need to add 3 didSet methods for accessing or is there any option to add three properties as input parameters in didSet. What to do?

Comment: You said to add didSet method to display data, If we have 5 properties then we need to take 5 didSet methods to displaying in viewWillAppear. Tell how to use.

Comment: No, I said to set the values in the source view controller's `didSelectRowAt` method. (Set instance variables in the destination view controller. Don't try to set the IBOutlets.) Then, in the destination view controller's viewWillAppear, install values from all of your various properties into your user interface.

Comment: i'm adding many didSet methods, can you send a reference program related to that?